# Dragging a touch along a row of UIButtons

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I have a row of say 10 UIButtons along the bottom of the iPhone screen. The user can TouchUpInside each of these. I'd also like to allow the user to drag their finger along the row, deselecting the previous button that was touched when the finger is over the next. This kind of behaviour is seen on iPhone's keyboard.

The obvious thing to try is UIControlEventDragOutside or UIControlEventDragExit to trigger the appropriate actions however these only work when the touch event is sufficiently far away from the button. As my buttons must sit flush against each other this is not good enough for me.

Suggestions?